# Find the index of first integer inside a string in order to cut this string

Tags: java, string, indexing

I am currently having an annoying issue. I would like to find an index of the very first integer value inside a string in order to cut the string next.

```
String currentPlayerInfo = "97  Dame Zeraphine [TBC]    10  41.458  481 363 117";
String currentPlayerName = "Dame Zeraphine [TBC]"; // This ís a kind of output i would like to get from the string above
```

I have tried different solutions but I was not able to find a proper one in the end. I would be really glad if I could get some help.

Comment: *"I have tried different solutions"* - add them

Comment: will the player info string always contain `[...]` ?

Comment: If it is guaranteed that elements are split by exactly two spaces, then you can just split by them: `currentPlayerInfo.split(" {2}")`.

Comment: @Aominè no, it will not always be the case

Comment: @azro thank you, i will keep that in my mind

Comment: You removed the „41.458“, so you also want to remove floats?

Comment: Can you give more info on the structure of the input? Is it separated by a number of Strings? Does it have fixed length 'columns'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to use regular expressions, you can use pattern `^[\d\s]+(.*?)\s+\d`.

This will skip all numbers and spaces in beginning of String, and take everything up to a number of spaces followed by a digit.

This will only work if the `playerName` does not contain a digit (preceded by a space).

```
String currentPlayerInfo = "97  Dame Zeraphine [TBC]    10  41.458  481 363 117";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\d\\s]+(.*?)\\s+\\d");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(currentPlayerInfo);
String currentPlayerName;
if (matcher.find()) {
    currentPlayerName = matcher.group(1);
} else {
    currentPlayerName = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all numbers from your input to get that result, so you can use [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) with this regex [`\d+(\.\d+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/TjzZEm/1/) :

```
currentPlayerInfo = currentPlayerInfo.replaceAll("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?", "").trim();
```

Output

```
Dame Zeraphine [TBC]
```